# exam 483 - Support 32-bit and 64-bit system configurations c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

I am studying for exam 70-483, from Microsoft. I have this question:

> You are developing an application by using C#. You have the following
>   requirements: Support 32-bit and 64-bit system configurations. Include
>   pre-processor directives that are specific to the system
>   configuration. Deploy an application version that includes both system
>   configurations to testers. Ensure that stack traces include accurate
>   line numbers. You need to configure the project to avoid changing
>   individual configuration settings every time you deploy the
>   application to testers. Which two actions should you perform? (Each
>   correct answer presents part of the solution. Choose two.)
>
> A. Update the platform target and conditional compilation symbols for
>   each application configuration.
>
> B. Create two application configurations based on the default Release
>   configuration.
>
> C. Optimize the application through address rebasing in the 64-bit
>   configuration.
>
> D. Create two application configurations based on the default Debug
>   configuration
>
> Answer: B,D

Can someone please explain why is B and D the right answer? I would say that A and D or A and B are the right answer.

Comment: B and D is correct. all you need is a 32bits and a 64bits configuration for each mode you have. In this case it assume you only have the 2 basic one Debug and Release. If you had Beta and Post-Prod you would need 2 config for each as well.